# Trying to target all my input field in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I Cant get this Code to Work, I'm Trying to target all my **Input Field** to have a **onblur** and **onfocus** effect but no success at all.please help me.

I also tried using **getElementsByClassName** but it didn't work... :(

```
var inputArray = new Array( "ans01", "ans02", "ans03", "ans04", "ans05", "ans06" );     
for( var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ ) {
   answerInput = document.getElementById(inputArray[x]).value;
}       
var inputField = answerInput;
inputField.onfocus = function() {
   if (inputField.value == "Place your answer here") {
      inputField.value = "";
   }
};
inputField.onblur = function() {
   if (inputField.value == "") {
      inputField.value = "Place your answer here";
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems.  First, you need to move the functions into the for loop.  Otherwise, they will only be attached to the last input box.  Second, instead of using input.value inside the functions, you should use this.value.  Inside event handlers, "this" refers to the element that triggered the event.

Here is the complete code that worked for me:

```
var inputArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ )  {
    answerInput = inputArray[i];

    answerInput.onfocus = function() {
        if (this.value == "Place your answer here") {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }

    answerInput.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            this.value = "Place your answer here";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` and refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
   answerInput = document.getElementById(inputArray[x]).value;
```

Change this line to:

```
   answerInput = document.getElementById(inputArray[i]).value;
```

Can you spot the change?

Also, you should assign the `onfocus` and `onblur` functions inside the loop, otherwise only the last input will work.

```
var inputArray = new Array( "ans01", "ans02", "ans03", "ans04", "ans05", "ans06" );     
for( var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ ) {
    answerInput = document.getElementById(inputArray[i]).value;

    var inputField = answerInput;

    inputField.onfocus = function() {
       if (inputField.value == "Place your answer here") {
          inputField.value = "";
       }
    };

    inputField.onblur = function() {
       if (inputField.value == "") {
          inputField.value = "Place your answer here";
       }
    };
}
```

As, John showed in his code, it might be wise to use `getElementsByTagName("input");` for getting all `<input>` elements.